# When I install ubuntu or elementary OS, my laptop (Asus E200HA) keyboard does not work. But it works perfectly fine when I install Lubuntu

Tags: keyboard, suspend, asus

The touchpad seems to be working fine, except for the left or right key. When I click on them, the shutdown/reboot/sleep etc menu pops up and on clicking any key from the keyboard, the laptop simply shuts down. If I connect any external USB mouse or keyboard, it works perfectly fine.

Any idea how I can install the onboard keyboard correctly?
There's another question on the thread facing the same issue but the answer doesn't point out how exactly to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue when I installed Loki 0.4.1. (I was eagerly hoping for the SD  card to be fixed) but I faced the same issue on my Asus E200HA

So reverted back to 0.4.0. this release doesn't have this issue (pressing a button on the on-board keyboard and going to sleep). Maybe this could help you as well?

The only things I didn't get working was the SD card reader and audio. The rest was pretty stable.